# UWP NavigationView prevent unload Pages

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, uwp-navigation

I'm using a NavigationView and when I navigate to a different page the previous one is unload, this is OK for some pages (and should be that way), but for other pages I wanted to  maintain the Page loaded even if I navigate away from that Page.

Is this Possible?

The code for NavigationView

```
<NavigationView x:Name="NavigationView"
                MenuItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Items}"
                MenuItemTemplate="{StaticResource NavigationViewItem}"
                SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
                SelectionChanged="OnSelectionChanged">

    <Grid>
        <Frame x:Name="frame">
            <Frame.ContentTransitions>
                <TransitionCollection>
                    <NavigationThemeTransition/>
                </TransitionCollection>
            </Frame.ContentTransitions>
        </Frame>
    </Grid>
    <NavigationView.PaneFooter>
        <NavigationViewItem ContentTemplate="{StaticResource NavigationViewItemProfile}"
                            Content="{x:Bind ViewModel.UserInfo}"/>
    </NavigationView.PaneFooter>

</NavigationView>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set page's `NavigationCacheMode` to `NavigationCacheMode.Required` in its constructor or `XAML` declaration.